# How can convert date with format Feb 20, 2019 inot 20-02-2019 using python?

Tags: python

I have the following date format
[image]

I tried to convert it into DateTime format using pandas or datetime package using the following code
`import datetime as dt
df_huawei['Date'] = df_huawei['Date'].apply(lambda x:dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f'))` but I got the following error

```
ValueError: time data 'May 31, 2019' does not match format '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f
```

I've read many solutions but my date format is not included in all discussion could you please help

Comment: The error is pretty clear, the string with the date that you are giving doesn't match the format you're claiming it is in.

Comment: `df_huawei['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df_huawei['Date'])` should work for you - that or explicitly provide a correct datetime format: see https://strftime.org/ for a reference of what the %'s mean...

Comment: @JonClements Thanks it's simple and it works very well thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import datetime as dt
dttmp=dt.datetime.strptime("Feb 20,2019","%b %d,%Y")
dtstr=dttmp.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
dtstr
```

Comment: Note: `%b` for abbreviated month names and `%B` for full month names.  OP didn't give a good example by choosing May.

Comment: @Haiz Thanks alot

Comment: I tried "May" and the code also works.  In the title, "Feb" is used, which means to use abbreviated month.

Answer (score 0):

Your format is wrong.
refer strptime documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

This will to the work for your case:

`import datetime as dt
dt.datetime.strptime('May 31, 2019', '%b %d, %Y')`

Comment: Note: `%b` for abbreviated month names and `%B` for full month names.  OP didn't give a good example by choosing May.

Comment: @Leon.fon Thanks a lot